# Linear-gradient: как сместить вниз изменение цвета?

Tags: html, css, градиент

Есть задача - сделать вот такой градиент:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать собственно изменение от #007234 к #27A42F, я знаю, но изменение это происходит равномерно:

```css
.top {
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #007234, #27A42F);
 height: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
```

А как сделать, чтобы изменение начиналось только в самом низу? Пробовал подставлять проценты, но что-то не очень получилось.

**P.S.**
В предложенном в ответе варианте появляется тёмная полоса на границе двух цветов:

```css
.top {
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #007234, #007234 80%, #27A42F 100%);
 height: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
```

Comment: В приведенном варианте ответа все нормально, а темная полоска — это не более, чем визуальный эффект. Чтобы от него избавиться, добавьте какой-то промежуточный цвет в градиент.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, ключевое слово "какой-то". Предложите свой вариант ответа, если знаете оптимальное решение. У меня есть только 2 цвета, какие цвета между ними являются промежуточными и где именно надо расставлять эти промежутки, я не знаю - потому и обратился за помощью.

Answer (score 2):

Можно указать проценты, на которых идет переход. Подробнее [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient).

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #007234, #007234 80%, #27A42F 100%);
```

Comment: В таком варианте на границе двух цветов - отчётливая тёмная полоса (я добавил в вопросе p.s. с примером как это выглядит). Можно ли от этой полосы как-то избавиться?

Comment: Можно задать любое число  шагов с процентами